# Create random list of size "n" containing elements from another list

Tags: python, list, random

I want to create random string filled with "S" and "O". For example, my desired output is like:

```
SSOSOOSO
OSOOSSOS
SSSOOSSO
OSOSOSOO
```

With my code I change randomly every line, so what is the way to change every position?

```
import random

rows = 4
columns = 8
char_list = ['S', 'O']

for i in range(rows):
    print(random.choice(char_list) * columns)
```

My current output:

```
SSSSSSSS
SSSSSSSS
OOOOOOOO
SSSSSSSS
```

Comment: The `* columns` part in the code doesn't multiply the *call* of `random.choice()`, but the *result* of a single call, that's why the items are identical in a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python 3.6+, you can simply use `random.choices()` to achieve this:

```
>>> import random
>>> char_list = ['S', 'O']

>>> random.choices(char_list, k=5)
['S', 'S', 'O', 'S', 'S']
```

Refer ["random.choices()" document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) for more details.

---

Hence your code will become:

```
import random

rows = 4
columns = 8
char_list = ['S', 'O']

for i in range(rows):
    print(''.join(random.choices(char_list, k=columns)))

# Output:
# SSOSSSSO
# OOSOSOOO
# SSSOOOOO
# OOOOSSSS
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the body of the loop to this:

```
print("".join([random.choice(char_list) for i in range(columns)]))
```

This way, you are calling `random.choice(char_list)` once every loop iteration of the list comprehension (= once per row per column), instead of only once per row, as in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a second loop to go through every column in every row:

```py
import python


rows = 4
columns = 8
char_list = ["S", "O"]

for i in range(rows):
    row = ""
    for j in range(columns):
        row += random.choice(char_list)
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) with str.join() and a list comprehension:

```
from random import choice
L = 8  # length of desired string
''.join([choice('OS') for x in range(L)])
```

Comment: Ah. @Timur Shtatland types faster than me.  Sadness

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy random.choice as it has a probability option, which you can add .5 to for each, then reshape.

```
from numpy.random import choice
choice(['S','O'], 32,
              p=[.5,.5]).reshape((8,4))


array([['O', 'S', 'S', 'O'],
       ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S'],
       ['S', 'S', 'O', 'S'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'S'],
       ['S', 'O', 'O', 'S'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'S'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
       ['O', 'S', 'S', 'O']], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sample out random indices for each row/column and load them with one of the characters and the remaining with other characters. It seems like you want exactly half of them to be filled with S and other half to be filled with O.

Something like the following can be done - which is actually very straight forward. However there are more efficient ways using numpy library:

```
import random

result = []
for i in range(rows):
    indx = random.sample(range(1,columns),columns//2)
    singleRow = []
    for j in range(columns):
        if j in indx:
             singleRow.append('S')
        else:
             singleRow.append('O')
    result.append(singleRow)
```